# Contar dígitos Racket

Tags: lista

Tengo una duda a cerca de como contar los dígitos de una lista, lo que tengo que hacer es hacer una fucnión que cuente los digitos contenidos en una lista
ejemplo

```
(cuentaD '(2   7   10    78))  >  6
```

He usado para contar el length pero me arroja 4, porque no lo está contando como dígito, tambien ya tengo un método para contar los digitos pero de un número y no una lista, alguien sabe como contar digitos en una lista?

Comment: Te recomiendo que veas esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3ExAU7QKt4[Es tema de lista][1]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedo recomendarte es hacer una funcion auxiliar donde puedas separar todos los digitos de una lista y luego calcular la cantidad. Por ej

---

```
(define (partir s)(map string (string->list s)))

(partir (list 2 7 10 78)) -> (list 2 7 1 0 7 8)

(define (cantidad l) (length (partir l))

Espero que te sirva, Saludos
```